# Was ALL Youtube traffic diverted to Pakistan despite some IP addresses not falling in the CIDR block that Pakistan registered. block

Tags: ipv4, ip-address

Youtube had previously registered the CIDR block 208.65.152.0/22 that contains the IP addresses 208.65.152.0 - 208.65.155.255

Pakistan then registered the CIDR block 208.65.153.0/24 that contains the IP addresses 208.65.153.0 - 208.65.153.255.

Due to the longer prefix, Youtube traffic was thus directed to Pakistan however what about the IP addresses 208.65.152.0-208.65.152.255 that is not contained in Pakistan's newly registered CIDR?  Was traffic still delivered there? #confused

Would appreciate clarification here! Thanks

Comment: I have found information stating that Youtube's DNS and Web Servers were contained in 208.65.153.0/24 (208.65.153.0-208.65.153.255) which falls within Pakistan's CIDR block. So could the other 256 IP addresses that do not fall within this block be internal unreachable addresses?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with a professional network under your control. You will need to ask Google about this.

Answer (score 1):

The most specific route is preferred. 24 is longer ("more specific") than 22, so it will be used. If they announced only one /24, then they only took over that one /24 out of the larger /22.